# C# Automatic Shows Button Disabled if seat already reserved

Tags: c#, button, panel

[image]

> So I have each panels for each time, the panel shows when u click the time from *timeComboBox*.

> I would like the buttons to be disabled if it is already in the data, for it to be not duplicated.

> If the data is already in the *database* or if the seat is reserved i would like the button to be disabled.

> Is it possible, where am I supposed to write the code in the book reservation or where the panels are or in the buttons :)

> This is how it looks right now:

[image]
[image]

> Here is the code of timeComboBox:

```
private void timeComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
if (timeComboBox.SelectedItem.ToString() == "8 am")
{
showSubMenu(panel1);
panel2.Visible = false;
panel3.Visible = false;// To Hide other panel when opening a panel.
panel4.Visible = false;
panel5.Visible = false;
panel6.Visible = false;
panel7.Visible = false;
panel8.Visible = false;
panel9.Visible = false;
}
if (timeComboBox.SelectedItem.ToString() == "9 am")
{
showSubMenu(panel2);
panel1.Visible = false;
panel3.Visible = false;
panel4.Visible = false;
panel5.Visible = false;
panel6.Visible = false;
panel7.Visible = false;
panel8.Visible = false;
panel9.Visible = false;
}
if (timeComboBox.SelectedItem.ToString() == "10 am")
{
showSubMenu(panel3);
panel1.Visible = false;
panel2.Visible = false;
panel4.Visible = false;
panel5.Visible = false;
panel6.Visible = false;
panel7.Visible = false;
panel8.Visible = false;
panel9.Visible = false;
}
if (timeComboBox.SelectedItem.ToString() == "11 am")
{
showSubMenu(panel4);
panel1.Visible = false;
panel2.Visible = false;
panel3.Visible = false;
panel5.Visible = false;
panel6.Visible = false;
panel7.Visible = false;
panel8.Visible = false;
panel9.Visible = false;
}
if (timeComboBox.SelectedItem.ToString() == "12 pm")
{
showSubMenu(panel5);
panel1.Visible = false;
panel2.Visible = false;
panel3.Visible = false;
panel4.Visible = false;
panel6.Visible = false;
panel7.Visible = false;
panel8.Visible = false;
panel9.Visible = false;
}
if (timeComboBox.SelectedItem.ToString() == "1 pm")
{
showSubMenu(panel6);
panel1.Visible = false;
panel2.Visible = false;
panel3.Visible = false;
panel4.Visible = false;
panel5.Visible = false;
panel7.Visible = false;
panel8.Visible = false;
panel9.Visible = false;
}
if (timeComboBox.SelectedItem.ToString() == "2 pm")
{
showSubMenu(panel7);
panel1.Visible = false;
panel2.Visible = false;
panel3.Visible = false;
panel4.Visible = false;
panel5.Visible = false;
panel6.Visible = false;
panel8.Visible = false;
panel9.Visible = false;
}
if (timeComboBox.SelectedItem.ToString() == "3 pm")
{
showSubMenu(panel8);
panel1.Visible = false;
panel2.Visible = false;
panel3.Visible = false;
panel4.Visible = false;
panel5.Visible = false;
panel6.Visible = false;
panel7.Visible = false;
panel9.Visible = false;
}
if (timeComboBox.SelectedItem.ToString() == "4 pm")
{
showSubMenu(panel9);
panel1.Visible = false;
panel2.Visible = false;
panel3.Visible = false;
panel4.Visible = false;
panel5.Visible = false;
panel6.Visible = false;
panel7.Visible = false;
panel8.Visible = false;
}
}
```

> Here is the code of Reservation Button:

```
private void reservationButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Reservation Button.
        string nameString = nameTextbox.Text;
        string mobileString = mobileTextbox.Text;
        string timeString = timeComboBox.Text;
        string seatNumberString = textBox1.Text;
        bool allPopulatedBool = nameString != string.Empty && mobileString != string.Empty && timeString != string.Empty && seatNumberString != string.Empty;
        if (allPopulatedBool)
        {
            //if the Form are completed.
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=(localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=LocalDB;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False");
            con.Open();
            string queryString = "INSERT INTO CustomersInfo VALUES(@CustomersName, @CustomersMobile, @CustomersTime, @seatNumber)";

            SqlParameter param1 = new SqlParameter();
            param1.ParameterName = "@CustomersName";
            param1.Value = nameString;

            SqlParameter param2 = new SqlParameter();
            param2.ParameterName = "@CustomersMobile";
            param2.Value = mobileString;

            SqlParameter param3 = new SqlParameter();
            param3.ParameterName = "@CustomersTime";
            param3.Value = timeString;

            SqlParameter param4 = new SqlParameter();
            param4.ParameterName = "@seatNumber";
            param4.Value = seatNumberString;

            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, con);
            command.Parameters.Add(param1);
            command.Parameters.Add(param2);
            command.Parameters.Add(param3);
            command.Parameters.Add(param4);

            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
            MessageBox.Show("Reservation has been Successfully Booked!", "Schedule Added", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            nameTextbox.Text = string.Empty;
            mobileTextbox.Text = string.Empty;
            timeComboBox.Text = string.Empty;
            textBox1.Text = string.Empty;
            panel1.Visible = false;
            panel2.Visible = false;
            panel3.Visible = false;
            panel4.Visible = false;
            panel5.Visible = false;
            panel6.Visible = false;
            panel7.Visible = false;
            panel8.Visible = false;
            panel9.Visible = false;
        }
        if (!allPopulatedBool)
        {
            //if the Form are not completed.
            MessageBox.Show("Please fill out all fields.", "Incomplete Entry", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Woah, you should really learn how to use lists for your advantage. That is so much duplicate code... Imagine you had 30 panels instead of 9

Comment: I will search it thank youuu :)

Comment: first i would rework all the `if` checks to a `switch` block, which is either better readable and can be changed more easily later on if f. e. your opening times change.
Second and more relevant question: Where do you write to, if a seat is occupied at a certain time and which database do you use?

Comment: I have 4 columns CustomersName, CustomersMobile, CustomersTime, seatNumber. I pick the time in the comboBox while if the button of seatNumber is pressed the number appears in the textBox1 then I save it to LocalDB. I will edit it and put the code of ReservationButton.

Comment: Basically I would follow the idea to pass the date and/or the time to the database and it returns the status of each seats. According to that I can then set the buttons in your panel to `enabled` or `disabled`. This would also getting you rid of a lot of duplicate code and lets you handle all the extra work with only _one_ panel. It's actually the chairs (so the `buttons`) to be adjusted to the given time

Comment: @ChuyaSiy maybe your table can't serve this situation very good in its present form. I suspect you wont come along with only using one table and store everything in there. I'm currently working on a model suggestion and then on a way how to build the query that gives you the information you need

Comment: how do I return the status of each seats sorry i'm just new but I will search it, am I supposed to put all the seats in the database?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225776/discussion-between-procra-and-chuya-siy).

Answer (score 0):

Please use lists and dictionaries to simplify your code.

```
private void timeComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // This would probably be a field instead of a local variable
    var allpanels = new List<Panel> {panel1, panel2, panel3, panel4, panel5, panel6, panel7, panel8, panel9};
    // Make all panels invisible
    // This would probably be a method instead of local code
    foreach (var panel in allpanels)
    {
        panel.Visible = false;
    }

    // This would probably be a field instead of a local variable
    var timepanels = new Dictionary<string, Panel> {{"8 am", panel1}, {"9 am", panel2}, {"10 am", panel3} /* ... */};
    // Make 1 panel visible
    var selectedTime = timeComboBox.SelectedItem.ToString();
    timepanels[selectedTime].Visible = true;
    showSubmenu(timepanels[selectedTime]);
}
```

But, one question is: why use one panel for each time? Wouldn't one panel be enough as long as it's updated properly?

Comment: Oh I didn't know it's possible I searched it before in the internet but I didn't saw ans but thank youu I will try it sometime :)

Comment: My approach will go the same way, modelling and writing the correct query will take some time though